# Find neighborhood for each ConnectedComponent region

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-c++, opencv3.0

I used SuperpixelSLIC from OpenCV to compute superpixels and get the labels of each one, now I need to compute the neighborhood for each label. For example, considering 8-connected case in the array below, the neighborhood for label 1 es {2, 5}, for label 2 is {1, 3, 4, 5}, for 3 is {2, 4} and for 4 is {2, 3}

```
111223333
112222334
122233344
555244444
```

How can I implement this efficiently using opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if OpenCV has a specific function for this.

If you want to build it yourself, you can use a data structure like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::set<int>> neighbors;
```

This is a hash map that associates a label (I use `int`, replace with whatever type you use in your labeled image) to a set of labels (the neighbors).

You would then iterate through each pixel, and examine its 8-connected neighborhood:

```
int label = image[ii,jj];
int other = image[ii+1,jj]; // this inside a loop over the neighborhood
if (label != other) {
   neighbors[label].insert(other);
}
```

The `insert` operation will have no effect if `other` was already in the set, so there is no need to explicitly check for that.

At the end of this process, `neighbors` will contain an entry for each label in the image, and iterating over this entry will give a sorted list of neighbors:

```
label = 2;
std::cout << "Neighbors for label " << label << " are: ";
for(auto n : neighbors[label]) {
   std::cout << n << ", ";
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

In your example should output:

```
Neighbors for label 2 are: 1, 3, 4, 5,
```

Comment: Yes, I did a similar thing. OpenCV give 2 Mat variables: Labels and Contours (for each label). I iterated over the contours (instead of labels to check only contours) and checked 8-connected neighborhood. I used an auxiliary Mat variable to check if the current pixel and neighbors were visited to avoid computacion too. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion